# Android Sherlock Action - ShareActionProvider Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I am using ShareActionProvider in my Sherlock ActionBar. I want to change the icon but not able to do so.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Even after Specify the Icon it takes the [Default Icon from the Holo Light Theme](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_share_holo_light.png)

Is there any way to reference the Icon and force change it via Program ?

Comment: clean and build your project in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am looking to customize the action bar, usually the first place I look is the ActionBarSherlock themes and styles.

I found that the Sherlock theme uses the "actionModeShareDrawable" as found in theme.xml file.

Try changing your theme to include the "actionModeShareDrawable" item directly.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be `R.java` file is not updated after your change So clean the workspace or re-build the project.